# Postgres 9.4 0 undefined symbol - PQhostaddr

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I have installed postgres9.4 on Ubuntu
I used to be able to run psql just fine.

**symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/postgressql/9.4/bin/psql: undefined symbol: PQhostaddr**

As per Craig's comment I did a little digging.

I confirmed using ldd that PQhostaddr is the only exception.

I also tried this:

$ sudo ldconfig -v | grep libpq
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once

/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so is the dynamic  linker, ignoring

```
libpq.so.5 -> libpq.so.5.7
```

I can however only see the directories in each place once. (not repeated)
I also can't find libpq

So generally not doing amazingly with this.  I would have assumed there was a method of updating libpq.so.5.7

Am I barking up the wrong tree? (Or just barking mad)

Comment: psql has nothing to do with psycopg2. Please give us the exact error psql gives you. We can't figure out what's happening with a just a phrase like "I can't seem to get it to run anymore"

Comment: Thanks Jerome - error in question

Comment: The `libpq` being found on the library path (`/etc/ld.so.conf` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`) is older than the version in 9.4. Use `ldd /usr/lib/postgressql/9.4/bin/psql` to find out which version is being linked to.

Comment: Thanks Craig, that makes sense.  I have libpq.so.5 being linked to.  I looked in ld.so.conf, which includes ld.so.conf.d which is blank (that doesn't seem good).  Also echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH is also blank (although it is defined) - also not good.  Thanks for bearing with me

Comment: @electrometro Ubuntu and I are recent acquaintances.  It is still sitting unloved on a dev server.  younes0 seemed to have better luck below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue but I was able to resolve it by completely removing postgresql with these commands.

```
apt-get --purge remove postgresql\*
 rm -r /etc/postgresql/
 rm -r /etc/postgresql-common/
 rm -r /var/lib/postgresql/
 userdel -r postgres
 groupdel postgres
```

Then reinstalling postgresql.

Comment: I've tried this and it still doesn't work.  I've even done 'sudo apt install libpq-dev'.  No luck.  Do you have any other ideas that might work?

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me: removed completely and reinstalled PostgreSQL packages (but the cluster)